# cannot access a closed stream: groupdocs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, annotations, groupdocs

I am using asp.net mvc with groupdocs, I am unable to view some files, when I am trying to view files, I am getting the below error,

Cannot access a closed Stream.

the error is coming on the below line of code

```
private static AnnotationImageHandler AnnotationImageHandler;
AnnotationImageHandler.GetDocumentInfo(documentPath, password); -- error is coming from here
```

this codes work fine with many of the documents, but not working with very few documents, what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GroupDocs.Annotation supports only these [file formats](https://docs.groupdocs.com/annotation/net/supported-document-formats/).

> but not working with very few document

Please make sure such documents are in the supported file formats list. However, if you are getting the exception for a supported file, please share following details:

- API version that you are using (e.g. 20.6, 20.10)
- Sample application
- Problematic file